# Viewing DOM using CEF

Tags: dom, view, chromium-embedded

I'm in need for help with being able to access and manipulate DOM using CEF.  I've been researching and have found that CEF only provides readability of the DOM with methods such as CefDOMDocument, ViewDOM, etc.  These are to be called only on the render process main thread, however, I'm not well versed in threading and am not sure where to implement methods within the CEF code (which .cpp file and under which class, etc.).  From there, I know CEF doesn't support manipulating the DOM directly but allows this ability through the use of JavaScript.

So my question...

Can someone please provide the information (an example would be extremely helpful) on where/how to access the DOM using CEF?  I have been attempting under this piece of code within cefclient_win.cpp...

```
CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(info, g_handler.get(),
      g_handler->GetStartupURL(), settings, NULL);
```

But I believe this is part of the browser process and not the render process...

If you were to also know how to then manipulate the DOM with JavaScript (I have found methods such as ExecuteJavaScript() but am facing the same problem with this as I am with viewing the DOM) that would be helpful too, but just an example on helping a beginner like me view the DOM through CEF would help tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find all you need to build your solution with this:
[dom_test.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/cef3/tests/cefclient/dom_test.cpp?r=689)

In this file, have a look to:

- line 84: Class which implement `CefDOMVisitor` (implement the Visit method)
- line 111: Visit the DOM

In order to visit the DOM here is the API documentation of the [CefDOMVisitor](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefDOMVisitor.html).
In the Visit method you can access to the [CefDOMDocument](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefDOMDocument.html) and you can start visiting the DOM.

There is also this [C# tutorial](http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2013/12/visiting-the-dom-with-cefglue/) you should have a look in order to understand how does it work.

Hope that helps.